# Is Ida supposed to be a subtle throwback (wink to the fans) to Serena?

Tags: pokemon

Serena in performer outfit:

[image: Serana smiling in a red off the shoulder dress with a big red bow on the front]

Ida in her outfit:

[image: Ida playing a string instrument in a blue dress]

They both have the same hair color and are wearing similar colored outfits they both have blue eyes and they both have a sort of strange personality.

Is Ida from ultra sun a subtle wink to the fans who watched Kalos Pokemon Serena?

Comment: I personally dont like serena but the resemblence is difficult to miss

Comment: "similar colored outfits"?? One is red, the other is blue.

Answer (score 6):

Highly unlikely. Besides the vaguely-similar hair and eye colours, the two barely resemble one another:

- Their hair colours are similar, but not identical, and their hairstyles are completely different (Serena's is short and neat, Ida's is long and extremely frizzy)
- Serena's outfit is red with pink and black details; Ida's outfit is blue with azure and red details. I'm not sure where you're getting "similar coloured outfits" from, in all honesty. Yes, they both have red in them, but it's far more prominent in Serena's outfit than Ida's.
- Their eye colours are different shades of blue, their actual eyes are different shapes, and Ida's eyes have subtle age lines to indicate that she's much older than Serena.
- "They have a sort of strange personality" is such a generic statement that I could apply it to about half the characters in any anime I've ever watched. If you want to make the point that Ida has the same personality as Serena, you'll have to be a lot more specific.

Considering the hundreds, of not thousands of character designs that the *Pokémon* anime has had to come up with over its 1,000+ episodes, I think this can easily be dismissed as coincidence. There have probably been other characters in the anime with strawberry-blonde hair and blue eyes; it doesn't mean there's necessarily any sort of connection between them.

Not to mention that if they wanted a throwback to Serena, they could have just used Serena herself.

Answer (score -3):

Yes but they couldnt use serena because she had (one) violent outburst in xyz and dark things like that cant be in sun and moon even though yes there are dark episodes in sun and moon to like stoutland dying but the difference is in sun and moon nobody fights each other everyone is at least always friendly and the other obvious difference is when ash was sad in sun and moon Lillie was nice to him but when ash was sad in xyz serena was mean to him

But of course their could always be lookalikes like ida know? Someone named Ida

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Do you have any evidence that Serena's "violent outburst" in XY was the reason they couldn't bring her back in Sun/Moon? This sounds like an unfounded assumption (and one that, as you admit, doesn't seem to make much sense).